# bulk data insert from text file to mysql database using python script

Tags: python, mysql, windows, text

I am having text file and want to convert that text file into mysql database using Python script.

The following MYSQL QUERY is working fine without any issues, I have checked the data in table manually.

```
LOAD DATA local INFILE 'C:/Users/Desktop/Excercise/text1.txt' 
INTO TABLE report(tablename)
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' ' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n
```

Where as same query with python script was not working, I am getting the below error.
table have already created

```
con=pymysql.connect(host='localhost',database='test',user='root',password='test123')
cursor=con.cursor()
cursor.execute("LOAD DATA local INFILE 'C:/Users/Desktop/Excercise/text1.txt' INTO TABLE general_report FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' ' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'")
```

While running the script on windows2012
Error:

> There is a problem: (3948, 'Loading local data is disabled; this must be enabled on both the client and server sides')

Your inputs are welcome, Thanks in advance !

Comment: add parameter **local_infile** for the connect method `pymysql.connect(..., local_infile=True)`

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have tried from my end like below con=pymysql.connect(host='localhost',database='test',user='root',password='test123',local_infile=True), no error but script is not pulling data from table, where as same query is working with ram mysql query,